# how to get sum of product price column with referance to other table column customer_id

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the `SUM` of product prices of a particular customer whose `id` and cart products I saved in the `cart` table. Prices are in the `products` table.

The table structures are as follows:

```
CART TABLE cart_id, customer_id, product_id, product_qty PRODUCTS TABLE product_id, product_cat, product_title, product_desc, product_price, product_img
```

How can I do that? I'm using the following `mysqli` and `php` code, but it returns  `NUll`:

```
"SELECT SUM(`product_price`) as total FROM products
INNER JOIN cart ON products.product_price = cart.customer_id
WHERE customer_id = '$c_id'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: Help us help you - please share the table structures.

Comment: Why is your query connecting `ON products.product_price = cart.customer_id` ? I doubt that the product price is the same as customer_id

Comment: The table structures are as follows 
CART TABLE 
cart_id, customer_id, product_id, product_qty PRODUCTS TABLE product_id, product_cat, product_title, product_desc, product_price, product_img

Comment: Who upvotes this stuff? See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

don't you mean something more along the lines of:

```
"SELECT SUM(`product_price`) as total
FROM cart
INNER JOIN product ON product.id = cart.product_id
WHERE cart.customer_id = '$c_id'";
```

hard to say as we do not know your DB structure but joining the tables as you do seems to make no sense

UPDATE: changed query after knowing the DB structure

Comment: The table structures are as follows CART TABLE cart_id, customer_id, product_id, product_qty PRODUCTS TABLE product_id, product_cat, product_title, product_desc, product_price, product_img

Comment: I updated the query according to your table structure